# Building Red-Black Tree from sorted array in linear time

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, big-o, red-black-tree

i know how to build it with n insertions ( each with O(log(n)) efficiency )
(n*log(n)) overall
,i also know that the equivalent structure of 2-3-4 tree can also be build with linear time from sorted array.
can anyone please provide a simple explanation about the red-black version?

Comment: Could you please elaborate us your effort showing the necessary part of the code?

Comment: i am not trying to code it. just to understand the concept.

Comment: If you know how to build a 2-3-4 tree, just do exactly the same thing but a red for a 3 node, and two reds for a 4 node in the usual correspondence.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No matter what kind of BST you are going to build. The algorithm will be the same. Only need to build balanced binary tree.

1. Place middle element to the current position
2. Place [begin; middle) elements to the left subtree.
3. Place (middle; end) elements to the right subtree.

This is O(N) algorithm. It can be shown, that the result tree will be balanced.

We have balanced tree, so by definition:

length(longest path) - length(shortest path) <= 1

So you need to mark all nodes as black, except the deepest nodes in the tree (mark them as red).

Comment: what about the coloring?

Comment: @SashaMN, Any link about the claim "it can be shown, that the result tree will be balanced"?

Comment: Also, do I understand correctly that this algorithm should be applied recursively?

Answer (score 4):

A complete binary tree of height *H* has *2^H-1* nodes.

To make a red black tree from a sorted list:

1. Remove every second item from the list until you have *2^H-1* items remaining for some *H*.  Note that you will always have enough.
2. Build a complete tree out of the remaining items, all black.
3. Now attach all the items you removed to the tree.  Each item will be a red node, attached to whichever of the black nodes around its proper position is a leaf.

The easiest way to do step (3) is just to do a pre-order traversal of the tree, attaching new red nodes to every black leaf until you run out of items.

NOTE:  Sasha's algorithm also works, but this one *obviously* works.

Answer (score 0):

From a functional data structure perspective: there is a paper for [Constructing Red-Black Trees](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.2171&rep=rep1&type=pdf), which discovered the pattern of continuous insertion and related it to 1-2 number system.

It's a fun read.

Comment: This page could not be found

Answer (score 0):

For a working example implemented in Java, you may want to check out the method `buildFromSorted(int level, int lo, int hi, int redLevel, ...)` in `Java.util.TreeMap`.

One more comment about Java in particular: Unfortunately, if you have your own data structured in a sorted manner (e.g. as sorted ArrayLists), it is not so easy to get it into a TreeMap in a linear manner. One possibility however is to create your own implementation of a `SortedMap` or `NavigableMap` which is backed up by an ArrayList internally. Then it is possible to use this constructor to efficiently construct the TreeMap:

```java
    MySortedMap myMap = new MySortedMap(keyArray, valueArray);
    new TreeMap<K, V> (myMap)
```

Here is some sample code for doing so:

```java
    public class MySortedMap<K,V> extends AbstractMap<K,V> implements NavigableMap<K,V> {

        private ArrayList<K> keyArray;
        private ArrayList<V> valueArray;

        public Set<Map.Entry<K,V>> entrySet() {
            return new EntrySet();
        }

        class EntryIterator implements Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> {

            int i;

            public EntryIterator () {
                i = 0;
            }


            @Override
            public boolean hasNext() {
                if (i < keyArray.size()) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public Map.Entry<K,V> next() {
                if (hasNext()) {
                    Map.Entry<K,V> en = new Entry<K,V> (keyArray.get(i), valueArray.get(i));
                    i++;
                    return en;
                } else {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        final class Entry<K,V> implements Map.Entry<K,V> {
            K key;
            V value;

            @Override
            public K getKey() {
                return key;
            }

            @Override
            public V getValue() {
                return value;
            }

            @Override
            public V setValue(V value) {
                this.value = value;
                return value;
            }

            public Entry(K key, V value) {
                this.key = key;
                this.value = value;
            }
        }

        class EntrySet extends AbstractSet<Map.Entry<K,V>> {
            public Iterator<Map.Entry<K,V>> iterator() {
                return new EntryIterator();
            }

            public int size() {
                return keyArray.size();
            }

            
        }

        public MySortedMap (ArrayList<K> keyArray, ArrayList<V> valueArray) {
            if (keyArray.size() != valueArray.size()) {
                throw new RuntimeException("Key and value arrays must have the same length!");
            }

            this.keyArray = keyArray;
            this.valueArray = valueArray;
        }

        ... some unused methods ...
    }
```